# Proving ($\left|\left|Ax\right|\right| = \left|\left|x\right|\right|$, for all $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$) $\implies A$ is unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As the title states, I'm trying to prove that $\left|\left|Ax\right|\right| = \left|\left|x\right|\right|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{C}^n\implies$ $A$ is unitary, where $A$ is a square matrix.

This is part of a larger problem and the only thing I 'know' for the purposes of this proof is that $\left|\left|Ax\right|\right| = \left|\left|x\right|\right|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, nothing else, e.g. I don't know that the rows or columns of $A$ are orthonormal.

Any hints on where I can start with this? I'm quite stuck.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: try playing around with the inner product.

Comment: Do you mean $x \in \mathbf{C}^n$ where $n$ is the dimension of your matrix? (and you are assuming $A$ is square?)

Comment: Yes, I did and the edits have been made, thank you. And yes, $A$ is definitely square.

Comment: Would the following suffice as a proof? $\left|\left|Ax\right|\right|^2 = <Ax,Ax> = (Ax)^*(Ax) = x^*A^*Ax$ And then $\left|\left|x\right|\right|^2 = x^*x$ and since $\left|\left|Ax\right|\right| = \left|\left|A\right|\right|$ then $x^*A^*Ax = x^*x$ which means $A^*A = I$, showing $A$ is unitary.

Comment: @Eric Seems good.But can you prove that $\forall x\in \mathbb C^{n\times 1}(x^*Mx=x^*Nx)\implies M=N$?

Comment: @Eric $A^{*}A=I$ implies that that $A$ is an isometry only. You also need to show that $AA^{*}=I$.

Comment: @GitGud I've been thinking about that and I know that $AB = CB$ does not imply that $A = C$. And if $x^*Mx = x^*Nx$, I'm not sure how to go about proving, if it's even possible, that $M=N$.

Comment: @Eric I think we need $M$ and $N$ hermitian, fortunately, this is the case.

Comment: @Indrajit It's safe to assume that someone who's dealing with this problem already knows that $XY=I\implies YX=I$.

Comment: @Eric [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281380/proving-an-implication-from-a-matrix-equation)'s your answer. It's easy to adapt to the complex case.

Answer (score 4):

By Polarization identities (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity), we have:
$$(Ax,Ay)=(x,y),\forall x,y\in \mathbb{C}^n,$$
which implies your result immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This proof is by induction. The base case is $n=2$.

We have, from the statement about the norms, that $x^{*}x=x^{*}A^{*}Ax$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{C}^2$. In particular, it is true for column vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$, the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$.  Plugging these in, we can see that the $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ entries of $A^{*}A$ are $1$. We can also see that the $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ entries of $A^{*}A$ are conjugates of each other, say $u$ and $\bar{u}$.

Next let $x=[1, 1]^T$. This gives us $2=2+u+\bar{u}$. Similarly, $x=[1, i]^T$ gives $2=2+u-\bar{u}$. From these equations we can conclude that both the real and imaginary parts of $u$ are $0$, so $u=0$. Hence $A^{*}A=I_2$

Now suppose $n>2$ and let $U=A^{*}A$. Let $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that all components are $0$ except the $i$th and $j$th. Given that $x^{*}x=x^{*}Ux$ we have that the principal submatrix $U[{i,j}]=I_2$. From this we conclude that $U=I_n$.

Comment: Sorry my TeX is not that good. If you have questions on the details, comment here.